# How to get location of an apps directory in the SD card?

Tags: android, android-external-storage

For example, say app A, writes a log file to external storage. Can app B pro grammatically retrieve the location of where app A wrote the file? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: no it's not possible

Comment: although it's probably somewhere in `/data/data/com.package.name.AppA.ApplicationName`

Comment: No @Shark it certainly is not there as that is internal memory.

Comment: App A can write everywhere on external storage. So no that is not possible. Unless you know the file name.

Comment: A directory in SD card has little to do with external memory. So your description is wrong.